# Maximum 2 semi join sub-selects are allowed

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, semi-join

While I'm querying on account object based on several conditions from different object I'm getting the below error:

> Maximum 2 semi join sub-selects are allowed .

The following the query which I'm using

```
select Id, Name, PersonHomePhone, PersonMobilePhone, Phone, PersonEmail, City__c from Account
where (RecordTypeId ='012280000000f14AAA' or RecordTypeId = '012280000006I5zAAE' or RecordTypeId = '012280000006I61AAE')
and Occupation__c='Office Staff'
and Id in (Select Contact__c From Vehicle_Relationship__c where Vehicle_ID__r.Class__c='C-Class'  AND  New_Used__c='New'  AND  Service_Advisor__r.Name='abcdef'  )
and Id in(Select Contact__c from Lead__c where CAC_Lead_Status__c='New'  )
and Id in(Select toRole__c From Account_Link__c where Sales_Representative__r.Name='abcdef'  )
and Id in(Select Contact_Id__c From Campaign_Member__c where Campaign_ID__r.Name='abcdef'  )
```

[image: Error]

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error itself says exactly what is wrong, you have more semi join sub-selects than are allowed. Those are the clauses that look like:

```
Id IN (/*sub-select*/)
```

You have four of them, so you'll need to split two out into separate queries. You can just populate a `Set<Id>` with the values from those queries you remove:

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Lead__c record : [/*query on Lead__c*/])
{
    contactIds.add(lead.Contact__c);
}
for (Campaign_Member__c record : [/*query on Campaign_Member__c*/])
{
    contactIds.add(record.Contact_Id__c);
}
```

Then you can modify your existing query.

```
...
AND Id IN :contactIds
AND Id IN (SELECT Contact__c FROM Account_Link__c WHERE ...)
AND Id IN (SELECT ToRole__c FROM Vehicle_Relationship__c WHERE ...)
```

It doesn't matter which sub-select queries you move out of your original query.

It's also worth noting that you should avoid `OR` clauses at all costs. They are not at all good for query performance. Instead of:

```
(RecordTypeId = '<id1>' OR RecordTypeId = '<id2>' OR RecordTypeId = '<id3>')
```

simply use:

```
RecordTypeId IN ('<id1>', '<id2>', '<id3>')
```

Not that you should be using hard-coded Ids either...even better would be to filter on `RecordType.DeveloperName`:

```
RecordType.DeveloperName IN ('<name1>', '<name2>', '<name3>')
```

Another advantage to filtering on the name instead is that it makes your code much easier to understand just by reading it.

Answer (score 3):

Taking a reference from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm), maximum 2 semi joins are allowed

> **Multiple Semi-Joins or Anti-Joins**

You can combine semi-join or anti-join clauses in a query. For example, the following query returns account IDs that have open opportunities if the last name of the contact associated with the account is like the last name “Apple

```
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN
  (
    SELECT AccountId
    FROM Contact
    WHERE LastName LIKE 'apple%'
  )
  AND Id IN
  (
    SELECT AccountId
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE isClosed = false
  )
```

You can use at most two subqueries in a single semi-join or anti-join query. Multiple semi-joins and anti-join queries are also subject to existing limits on subqueries per query.

> **Suggested solutions:**

1. Create separate queries to retrieve Contact__c from 4 different objects Vehicle_Relationship__c, Lead__c, Account_Link__c and Campaign_Member__c
2. Store those ids in `Set<Id>` as `contactIds`
3. Also store recordtype ids in a `Set<Id>`  as `recordtypeIds`
4. finally execute the query like this:

   ```
   SELECT Id, Name, PersonHomePhone, PersonMobilePhone, Phone, PersonEmail, City__c 
   From Contact
   WHERE RecordTypeId IN:recordtypeIds
   AND Id IN:contactIds
   AND Occupation__c='Office Staff'
   ```

**Moreover, as per your code, you are comparing AccountId with the Contact Ids returned from subqueries, so it will not work.**

I think it should be from Contact object rather than Account.

Comment: If you follow your numbers with `.` instead of `)` the parser converts it to an ordered list.